# Changing JSON options for NPGSQL + EFCore

Tags: json, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have some "NaN" data serialized into a JSONB column in a PostgreSQL table. It throws exception when trying to fetch from it with EFCore. There is this setting for System.Text.Json:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals
};
```

But how can I add this when setting up the DbContext with `UseNpgsql()` - or in any other way?

[**Update**]
I ended up creating a ValueConverter for that specific property and registering it with `HasConversion`. But that's an overkill, so if there is any more "global" approach I am still interested.

Comment: Im also having the same issue, where did you place ValueConverter?

Answer (score 0):

alright the following solved my issue:

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => {
                    
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals;
                    
                });
```

I also have a cammelcase convention above itthis applied inside

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

which should be inside your startup class or program(depending on how you set it up)

Comment: The problem with this is that it won't work outside the scope created for the http request.